# Find k>0 and m∈ℕ so that...

Tags: analysis

5. Find $k>0$ and $m∈ℕ$ so that $n^3-7n\ge\ kn$ for all integers $n\ge\ m$.

So I am not sure if there is some method I need to follow or if it is sufficient to just pick a random k and m that satisfies this? If so, $k=1$ and $m=10$ then:
$$n^3-7n\ge\ kn$$
$$n^3-7n\ge\ n$$
$$n^2-7\ge\ 1$$

Comment: The way it's worded seems like you just need to find an example, in which case your example is fine, although you could set $m=3$ with $k=1$ if you wanted to.

Comment: If the question does not specify how "small" $m$ must be or how large $k$ must be, your solution is fine. However, instead of the inequalities you show, I believe it would be better to write $n^3 = n^2 n \geq 10^2 n \geq 8n = 7n+n$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your example works, although you might want to better organize your proof for why it works a little; typically, the inequality that we want to prove should pop out at the end, not in the beginning. Here's a way to prove it with tighter parameters ($k = 2$ and $m = 3$) and a single chain of inequalities:
\begin{align*}
n^3 - 7n
&= n(n^2 - 7) \\
&\geq n(3^2 - 7) &\text{since } n \geq m = 3 \\
&= 2n \\
&= kn &\text{since } k = 2 \\
\end{align*}